# How do I add unsubscribe link to emails sent via Mandrill

Tags: email, mandrill, unsubscribe

How do I add unsubscribe link to emails sent via Mandrill automatically. Specifically, I need a feature in Mandrill not something I would have to develop at my end.

Answer (score 4):

Just add a link like the following:

```
<a href="*|UNSUB:http://mywebsite.com/unsub|*">Click here to unsubscribe.</a>
```

to your emails and Mandrill will put an unsubscribe link and will also provide the backend mechanism to automatically unsubscribe the user. This is done by adding the email address to your [Rejection Balcklist](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/22880521-What-is-a-rejected-email-Rejection-Blacklist-) in your account.

For more details, please see the [original documentation](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583017-Can-I-add-an-automatic-unsubscribe-link-to-Mandrill-emails-)